# Error in the exercise of oop

Tags: php, oop

Another error arose in another exercise, this now appears 
Links are below the image, copy and paste in browser

ContaPoupanca.class.php  imgur.com/f0g95ke

Conta.class.php  imgur.com/ykV7tv6

index.php  imgur.com/ZOigglQ

error  imgur.com/9GoDaeu

Comment: You were calling parent constructor along with parameters but its not defined within your parent class

Comment: for gods sake: use codeshare.io, pastebin.com or codepad.io in the future. or at least post your code in a usefull manner.

Comment: Another error?  You're assuming that every person reading this has read your previous question.  Maybe a link if it's relevant?  Are you asking SO users to do your college homework for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because there is no constructor in the `Conta` class.

Because, in the child class `ContaPoupanca`, you called the constructor of the parent class which is `Conta` like this:

```
parent::__construct($Agencia, $Codigo, $DataCriacao, $Titular, $Senha, $Saldo);
```

Therefore, to make this work, the parent class `Conta` should have a constructor like this:

```
public function __construct($Agencia, $Codigo, $DataCriacao, $Titular, $Senha, $Saldo) {
    // Do what you need to do here.
}
```

On a side note apart from this question, you haven't defined the functions with an encapsulation keyword. That is either "public", "private" or "protected".

Comment: Could show an example, here is the code.  class Conta{
  public $Agencia;
  public $Codigo;
  public $DataCriacao;
  public $Titular;
  public $Senha;
  public $Saldo;
  public $Cancelada;

  function Retirar($quantia){
    if($quantia > 0){
      $this-> Saldo -= $quantia;
    }
  }

  function Depositar($quantia){
    if($quantia > 0){
      $this-> Saldo += $quantia;
    }
  }

  function ObterSaldo(){
    return $this-> Saldo;
  }
}